# ESRI File Geodatabase with a field calculator with an incrementing number

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, field-calculator, file-geodatabase

I've got a python script that runs on the Field Calculator of a ESRI File Database.  Right now it runs correctly in that it will increment the last three digits of the value.  But this is a script that is run as part of post processing so it will be run everytime there are new entries in the feature class.  My question is how can I modify this so that every time it runs it will look at the last four digits of the FacilityID and increment from there below is a screenshot of my attribute table:

[image]

EDIT: 
And below is my Python script I need to modify.

```
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor("Telecommunications Line")
fac_id_values = [int(row.FACILITYID[-4:]) for row in cur]

maximum_value = max(fac_id_values)
if maximum_value:
 rec= maximum_value 
else:
 rec = 0

def autoIncrement(): 
 global rec 
 pStart = 1  
 pInterval = 1 
 if (rec == 0):  
  rec = pStart  
 else:  
  rec += pInterval  
 return "COMLI" + "11" +  format(rec, '03d')
```

Ok after running the code above I got this as a result.  It overwrote the previous values as shown above.  The First item should have a FacilityID of COMLI111001.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can loop through the FC first and find them maximum value.

Example:

```
import arcpy
nullvalues = ["", " ", None, 0]
# Loop through and get Max value
cur = arcpy.SearchCursor("Telecommunications Line")
fac_id_values = [int(row.FACILITYID[-4:]) for row in cur if row.FACILITYID not in nullvalues]

max_value = max(fac_id_values)

# Loop through and Calculate new values
cur = arcpy.UpdateCursor("Telecommunications Line")
for row in cur:
    max_value = max_value + 1
    if row.FACILITYID in nullvalues:
        row.FACILITYID = "COMLI1" + str(format(max_value,'04d'))
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

This should ensure that you only update Null values.

Comment: [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are awesome!

Comment: Yes, this could all be put into 1 line, but for readablity, i chose to seperate it into 3.   max_value = max([int(row.FACILITYID[-4:]) for row in arcpy.SearchCursor("YOUR FC")])

Comment: I'm always a fan of readability, and the list comprehension allowed you to take what would be even more verbose language, compress it to a single line, and still end up with three highly readable lines. Features like these make me enjoy working with Python after toiling for too long with Javascript ;)

Comment: Totally agree!!

Comment: So I was going to implement this so if Maximum_value is not null then set rec=maximum_value right?

Comment: And by YOUR FC you mean FacilityID right?

Comment: yes to the max value question - the YOUR FC is the name of your feature class!

Comment: Ok I tried and it over wrote the FacilityID as shown above.  I'd like this to only run on records that don't have a FacilityID.  See My edit above.

Comment: OK then, I changed my cursor in my answer to reflect only valid values!

Comment: Ok I ran it and I got a error saying A field name was not found or there where unbalanced quotation marks.

Comment: Modified my answer again. This is how i would do the whole thing.

Comment: So I am getting a ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence on max_value = max(fac_id_values)  What do I do there?